# Unable to run script because of the 'å's presence in my script

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, python-3.5

Here is the line that causes the error:

```
emner = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Armbåndsure og lommeure')
```

And the output:

```
  File "test.py", line 96
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe5' in file test.py on line 96, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I need to have this "å" in my script there is no way around it, I cant replace it. How do I "allow" it to be in my script. I know its something about unicode, but I dont know that much about it. So I thought a kind person would help me out here on stack overflow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What encoding did you actually save this file in?

Comment: I just pasted your string and it printed properly (python 3). No encoding needed.

Comment: It looks like you probably saved this file in something like Latin-1. Save it in UTF-8 instead.

Comment: no way around it? what about `'Armb\xe5ndsure og lommeure'` ?

Comment: Its solved guys, just forget it and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have saved your file in a non-UTF8 encoding, but Python 3 interprets files as UTF8-encoded by default.

Either save the file as UTF8 from whatever text editor you are using, or add the line `# coding: latin-1` as the first or second line in your file.

If you are unable to do either, you can replace the non-ASCII text with an ASCII-only escape sequence: `'Armb\xe5ndsure og lommeure'`